# SQL insert multiple couples with kind of array in R-value?

Tags: mysql, sql, plsql

I would like to know if it is possible to insert multiple values in an `INSERT` statement with something like this:

```
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES ( constant , ARRAY(multipleValues) );
```

If this is not possible, I will use a stored procedure. My question is more for curiosity than for real purpose, since I'm using a working loop which inserts records once at a time and that does the job.

Comment: Why is this question tagged both [tag:mysql] and [tag:plsql]?  Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @eggyal: Oops I just noticed it. It seems I clicked too quickly on the tags and did not pay attention... There is no PL/SQL over there, you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL does not have an array data type.  In order to pass an array from your application code into a MySQL query, you will need to explode it into a string.

You can then do:

```
INSERT INTO myTable
VALUES
  (constant, value1),
  (constant, value2),
  (constant, value3),
  -- etc.
```

Or:

```
INSERT INTO myTable
SELECT constant, t.value
FROM (
  SELECT value1 AS value
UNION ALL
  SELECT value2
UNION ALL
  SELECT value3
-- etc.
) AS t
```

Generally the first form is more concise, however the second form may be more useful if there is a large number of constant columns.

Comment: Okay, +1 for the idea. Do you think tha a join could bring me "the left side" with the const ?

Comment: I'm sure it is possible with something like SELECT lefSide, rightSide FROM (SELECT 'const' AS leftSide FROM DUAL) T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT rightSide FROM myTable) T2 ; Isn't it?

Comment: @Benj: What's wrong with directly using a literal, as above?  Not sure I follow.

Comment: Wouldn't UNION ALL be quiet heavy/long with thousands of values ?

Comment: I understand what is "complicated" : I did not explain what I want to do. I wondered if it is possible to build a query looking like "INSERT INTO table VALUES (" + myConst + "), SOME_ARRAY_TRICK(" + implode(array of values) + ");". I finally build this query with a simple INSERT ... SELECT myConst,myRValues FROM myTable. Thanks a lot eggyal, your query put me on the rails. I accept this answer since it has helped me solving my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert multiple records in VALUES section as follows

```
 INSERT INTO example (example_id, name, value, other_value)
 VALUES
 (100, 'Name 1', 'Value 1', 'Other 1'),
 (101, 'Name 2', 'Value 2', 'Other 2'),
 (102, 'Name 3', 'Value 3', 'Other 3'),
 (103, 'Name 4', 'Value 4', 'Other 4');
```

Comment: Sorry, but it is not what I wanted to mean : i'm seeking for a manner to pass only one value to "the left side" and a lot of values to "the right side", making SQL inserting records like [ const , value[i] ]

Answer (score 0):

[As I said in comment to @eggyal,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12976455/sql-insert-multiple-couples-with-kind-of-array-in-r-value#comment17623944_12976681)
There is the solution I found :

```
INSERT INTO
    t1
SELECT
    "theConstant",
    subValue
FROM
    subTable
;
```

Thanks to @eggyal for the primary idea.